# Subgroup of index p in an infinite p-group?

Tags: group-theory, p-groups, infinite-groups

Does an abelian infinite $p$-group ***always*** contain a subgroup of index $p$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of an infinite (abelian) $p$-group?

Comment: No, the proper subgroups of the Prüfer $p$-groups ${\mathbf Z}(p^\infty)$ are all finite and cyclic.